npx expo run ios : Failed to create the native directory
When trying to run npx expo run ios, I encountered the error message Failed to create the native directories with npm exiting with non-zero code: 243.
This error suggests an issue with the native directories in my React Native project.
I have tried deleting the ./ios and ./android directories as suggested, but the error persists. How can I resolve this issue and successfully run my React Native app on iOS using Expo?

SOLUTION ✅
After spending time to really understand the problem source, here is the solution that worked for me.
Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
To permanently fix this problem, please run:
   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/mac/.npm"
This solved the problem for me.

Thank you a lot :) life saver
